# Solr search with AND operator with strict ordering

Tags: solr

Let's say I have a query like:

```
search_field:A AND search_field:B
```

that looks for a target that contains both `A` and `B`

so the result would be:

```
AcccccB
BcccccA
...
```

However, is there a way to keep the ordering of the query so it works like with an order?

For example with pseudo query

```
search_field:A AND THEN search_field:B
```

which would yield

```
AcccccB
...
```

The logic is that based on the query, it looks for `A` and `B` but with that order only. So while `BcccccA` had both `A` and `B`, it was filtered out since `B` came before `A`.

### Tried

- Tried [wild card](https://solr.apache.org/guide/6_6/the-standard-query-parser.html), but it doesn't work for phrases:

```
AcccccB
Acc ccB
Bcc Acc < can't filter out
```

Thank you in advance let me know if I can make the question more clear.

Comment: How is `search_field` [tokenized](https://solr.apache.org/guide/6_6/tokenizers.html)?  Tokens may appear more than once in a document.  An index is a table from tokens to ids of documents that contain the token, not to the set of all token locations within the document.   (In a physical book, the index is usually a table from words to pages, not to the set of word locations within a page.)

Answer (score 2):

**1. string**: IF the value of `search_field` is stored as one token (string [field type](https://solr.apache.org/guide/6_6/field-types-included-with-solr.html)), THEN you may be able to use a wildcard pattern or a regular expression to match the value.  To match single-token string type fields, where an A appears before a B:

```
q=search_field:*A*B*
```

or

```
q=search_field:/.*A.*B.*/
```

For more, see this [Solr Regex Tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20161030170947/http://www.openjems.com/solr-regex-tutorial/).  In the tutorial example the same value is stored twice, once in a string field and once in a text field.

An example of this in the Solr "techproducts" example data is the field pair: `author` (text) and `author_s` (string).  Order is siginificant: The query `q=author_s:*g*t*` returns books by George R.R. Martin, and the query
`q=author_s:*t*g*` returns a book by Grant Ingersoll.

**2. text:** IF the value of `search_field` is indexed as multiple tokens (such as when each word is a token), and A is in a separate token from B, THEN you may be able to use the [Complex Phrase Query Parser](https://solr.apache.org/guide/6_6/other-parsers.html#OtherParsers-ComplexPhraseQueryParser) with `inOrder=true` (default).

*2a. text, adjacent tokens:*  IF A and B must appear in *adjacent* tokens in the field value, THEN a complex phrase query with no ~ proximity can be used:

```
{!complexphrase}search_field:"*A* *B*"

{!complexphrase}search_field:"/.*A.*/ /.*B.*/"
```

Adjacency example: In the "techproducts" sample data, `{!complexphrase}author:"*t* *g*"` does return the book by Grant Ingersoll, but `{!complexphrase}author:"*g* *t*"` does not return the books by George R.R. Martin.

*2b. text, nearby:* IF the tokens are not necessarily adjacent but are nearby, THEN use a complex phrase query, suffixed with a ~ proximity token count.  For example, within 10 words or tokens:

```
{!complexphrase}search_field:"*A* *B*"~10

{!complexphrase}search_field:"/.*A.*/ /.*B.*/"~10
```

In the "techproducts" sample data, `{!complexphrase}author:"*g* *t*"~10` does return the books by George R.R. Martin and not the book by Grant Ingersoll.

Note: neither 2a nor 2b will match single token values where A is followed by B.  To also include single-token value matches, specify the OR of a single token pattern and a multiple token pattern:

```
{!complexphrase} search_field:*A*B* OR search_field:"*A* *B*"~10
```

Answer (score 1):

If the distance between A and B is less than or 99 positions - and they're tokens by themselves and not part of another token, you can [use the surround query parser](https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_11/other-parsers.html#surround-query-parser):

```
q={!surround}99w(A,B)
```

`99` is the maximum distance, `w` means ordered search (`n` would mean unordered).